# Is there a difference between asterisk -rvvvvvv and /etc/init.d/asterisk restart

Tags: amazon-web-services, asterisk, sip, sip-server

is there a difference between `asterisk -rvvvvvv` and `/etc/init.d/asterisk restart`

Which one will make use of latest changes of sip.conf and extensions.conf? Though I do sip reload and diaplan reload I would like to know the difference between  asterisk -rvvvvvv and /etc/init.d/asterisk restart ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use following commands to control asterisk engine running as background daemon.

```
/etc/init.d/asterisk start
/etc/init.d/asterisk stop
/etc/init.d/asterisk restart
```

However contrary to above, following command is for accessing asterisk via command line interface ( asterisk cli )

```
asterisk -rvvvvv
```

Comment: And what is core restart now for?

Answer (score 0):

Command

```
asterisk -r
```

connect you to already running in background asterisk daemon. It not start asterisk, so you get error if it not running.

```
asterisk -rvvvvvv
```

Do same, but increase verbosity of output to 6.

For full list of allowed options see http://man.cx/asterisk(8)

If you want start asterisk, you have run asterisk without -r(reconnect) or use startup scripts(for init v4 such scripts is /etc/init.d/asterisk, that will not work for modern setup like redhat 7 wich use systemd)

Comment: And what is core restart now for?

Comment: It request restart of asterisk daemon process.